# How do I create a GitHub Action to run Jest tests with Yarn?

Tags: node.js, github, jestjs, yarnpkg, github-actions

I use [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/) to run my [Jest](https://jestjs.io/) tests.

`package.json`

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  }
}
```

```sh
yarn test
```

I want to create a [GitHub action](https://github.com/actions) to run my tests when I merge commits in GitHub. The [Node Starter Workflow](https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/blob/master/ci/node.js.yml) runs tests with NPM. But I want to run them with Yarn.

How do I create an action to run my tests?

Comment: https://github.com/marketplace?utf8=%E2%9C%93&type=actions&query=Yarn?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use the [Node Starter Workflow](https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/blob/main/ci/node.js.yml) but replace the NPM portion with Yarn commands. For example:

```yaml
name: Node CI

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [10.x, 12.x, 14.19.1]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    - run: yarn install
    - run: yarn test
```

Comment: Just so you know, `yarn` is [installed](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/software-installed-on-github-hosted-runners) in all the environments

Comment: This workflow fails to test with ```Run yarn test:unit:coverage
  yarn test:unit:coverage
  shell: /bin/bash -e {0}
yarn run v1.22.5
error Command "test:unit:coverage" not found.
```
My pacakge .json

```"test:unit:coverage": "jest --coverage",```

Comment: @smac89 Yes, you are correct. This action assumes that. The action's purpose is to install Yarn dependencies—in this case Jest—and run a Yarn command.

Comment: @smac89 new link: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/publishing-packages/publishing-nodejs-packages#publishing-packages-using-yarn